# ANSIBLE - How create an array with stdout_lines filter by column

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Morning,

with ansible i have this stdout_lines :

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "1 peot 11135198 NY",
        "1 LIOS 106075056 berlin",
        "1 EASD 10828842 london",
        "1 APES 20789896 local",
        "1 PZSA 21705924 paris"
    ]
}
```

I need to get the second and fourth column and store it in an array . but I don't find example with filter on column.

so what is the better solution ? with Ansible ou in Jinja2 ?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"I need to get the second and fourth column and store it in an array."*

A: It's possible to use `regex_replace`. For example

```
    - set_fact:
        myarray: "{{ stdout_lines|
                     map('regex_replace', myregex, myreplace)|
                     list }}"
      vars:
        myregex: '^\s*(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s*$'
        myreplace: '\2 \4'
    - debug:
        var: myarray
```

give

```
    "myarray": [
        "peot NY", 
        "LIOS berlin", 
        "EASD london", 
        "APES local", 
        "PZSA paris"
    ]
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: yes it's work perfectly ! thanks for your help ! I think i use this code for many things !

Answer (score 0):

I try to decline your code , but something escapes me .
for get the 2 first column of find result.stdout_lines :

extract :

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11135198 Sep 25  2018 /root/setup/silinstall/nnstall
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 106075056 Dec 19 14:33 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10828842 Jan 27  2015 /usr/lib/libsssymm-dmx.so
```

if i want only the first and 5th columns , i set the vars like this

```
  vars:
    myregex: '^\s*(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s*$' (number of columns)
    myreplace: '\1 \5'
```

the result :

```
    "myarray": [
        "-rwxr-xr-x 1 Sep",
        "-rw-r--r-- 106075056",<-----------why this error ???
        "-rwxr-xr-x 1 Jan",
        "-rwxr-xr-x. 1 Aug",
        "-rwxr-xr-x 1 Sep"
    ]
}
```

I don't understand why i get the wrong column.